# How to properly unit test a class that gets file from an FTP server

Tags: junit, mockito, ftp-client

In fact, my question is divided into two parts.

1. How do I isolate my test from outside but still make sure that the functionality works?
2. How can I mock the apache commons FtpClient class using Mockito? When I mock it, I get null at:

> InputStream inputStream =
>            ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(ftpParameters.getSourceFileName());

Here's the test class:

```java
public class SimpleFtpFileImporterTest {
   FtpParameters ftpParams =new FtpParameters();
   SimpleFtpFileImporter fileImporter=new SimpleFtpFileImporter();
   FTPClient ftpMock= mock(FTPClient.class);



@Before
public void startup(){
    this.ftpParams.setServer("10.0.206.126");
    this.ftpParams.setPort(21);
    this.ftpParams.setUserName("mikola");
    this.ftpParams.setPassword("password");
    this.ftpParams.setSourceFileName("readme.txt");
}


@Test
public void returnNullWhenFileCouldNotBeFetchedCompletely() throws IOException{
    when(ftpMock.completePendingCommand()).thenReturn(false);
    fileImporter=new SimpleFtpFileImporter(ftpMock);
    byte[] bytes= fileImporter.downloadFile(ftpParams);
    assertNull(bytes);
}

}
```

And here's the system under test:

```java
public class SimpleFtpFileImporter implements IFileImporter {

private FTPClient ftpClient;

static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleFtpFileImporter.class);

static {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("config/log4j.properties");
}

/**
 * Creates a SimpleFtpFileImporter class instance passing an FtpClient.
 * This constructor helps create unit tests by passing any kind of FTPClient, eg. an http ftp client.
 *
 * @param ftpClient An FTPClient object
 */
public SimpleFtpFileImporter(FTPClient ftpClient) {
    this.ftpClient = ftpClient;
}

public SimpleFtpFileImporter() {

}
/**
 * Gets the file specified from the specified FTP server
 *
 * @param ftpParameters An FtpParametrs object that bears the needed information
 * @return File in byte array if successful, otherwise null
 */
public byte[] downloadFile(FtpParameters ftpParameters) {
    if (this.ftpClient == null)
        this.ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    if (!ftpParameters.isProperlyPopulated()) {
        logger.warn("Not all FTP parameters have been set. Execution will halt.");
        throw new FtpParametersNotSetException("Ftp parameters not properly set.");
    }
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(ftpParameters.getServer());
        ftpClient.login(ftpParameters.getUserName(), ftpParameters.getPassword());
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        logger.info("FTP connection succesfully established. Preparing to retrieve file:"+ftpParameters.getSourceFileName());

        InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(ftpParameters.getSourceFileName());
        if (inputStream != null) {
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            boolean success = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
            logger.info("File received");
            inputStream.close();
            if (success) {
                return bytes;
            } else{
                logger.warn("File fetching process could not be through. Returning null.");
                return null;
            }
        }else{
            logger.warn("Wrong file name specified. File name:"+ftpParameters.getSourceFileName());
            throw new RuntimeException("Wrong file name specified");
        }


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Problem while trying to get file from remote FTP. Message: " + ex.getMessage() + " \n\r" + ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

It seems mocked FtpClient object is not suitable for making real thing, although I supply all the needed parameters (host, port, userName and password)

Comment: I am kinda surprised. This question looks like it was written by a newbie asking the first time "why is my code not working". Seriously: provide a [mcve]. What you are asking for is "daily business" in mocking land; so for sure, you got some simple bugs in your code ;-)

Comment: Nnnnnn  Ok, I'll add some code then

Comment: See my updates to my answer please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer that part that can be answered so far - you have to learn how to write **testable** code; a good starting point would be these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79).

There is already a misunderstanding on your side: *It seems mocked FtpClient object is not suitable for making real thing*.

Exactly. A mock is a **mock**, an empty **test stub**. It doesn't do anything real. That is the whole point of using mocks. They are empty shells that do nothing but provide the behavior that you specify for them.
What I mean: the object created by Mockito is **not** a true FtpClient. It is just a **mock** that "looks" like an FtpClient. It doesn't have **any** connection to the "real" FtpClient" class. In other words: yes, you can call the methods on it that FtpClient has, but they are all **empty**. They do nothing (well, they do what you **specify** them to do their).

The point is: you use mocks to **decouple** you completely from an external implementation. By giving a **mock** to your code under test, you simply can **ignore** everything that the "real" class is doing.

Looking at your code and the "actual" problem:

```
InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(
```

In order to make that work, you have to **configure** your **mock** in order to return something **useful** when `retrieveFileStream()` is called!

What I mean is: you already do:

```
when(ftpMock.completePendingCommand()).thenReturn(false);
```

to tell Mockito: when `completePendingCommand()` is called, then return `false`. You need to do that for **every** method that your code under test is calling!

Beyond that; many problems with your code, like:

```
public SimpleFtpFileImporter() {
}
```

Should **not** be empty; instead, you should be doing something like:

```
public SimpleFtpFileImporter() {
 this(new FtpClient());
}
```

Simple answer there: fields should be **final** by default (unless you have good reasons to not make them final):

```
private final FTPClient ftpClient;
```

and the compiler would have **told** you that you forgot to init that field! In your case there is **absolutely** no reason to keep that field not init'ed upon construction. That just makes the whole class more complicated and harder to test.

Comment: Thanks for all those hints. But 1. What about isolation of the test from outside? 2. What is the difference between the FtpClient object created by calling `new FtpClient()` and the one created by the calling `Mockito.mock(FtpClient.class)`? Why don't I get null with the former one, but I get null with the latter one? Does Mockito have control on how constructor of the FtpClient instantiates an object?

Comment: More updates (second paragraph). You still dont get that a MOCK has NOTHING to do with the "original" class.

Comment: Man, now, how can I not accept this as just the correct answer? Thanks man, for both making me understand the mocks and a bonus `final` tip.

Comment: So if, mock just creates a skeleton of a class, it means it sees the internals through reflection. Hmm, now I see why we better mock interfaces, instead of classes.